# nginx proxy_pass to Jboss+Spring/Websphere+Portal projects

Tags: spring, jboss, nginx, websphere, websphere-portal

I have an nginx up at the front serving as a proxy to two servers, one running Websphere Portal Server and one running Spring on a Jboss server.

I'm currently having problems with the proxying of certain requests, for instance, I have the following:

```
server{
    listen:8080;
    server_name:localhost;

    location /jbossSpring/ {
        proxy_pass http://177.21.1.15:9000/Spring_project/;
    }

    location /webspherePortal/ {
        proxy_pass http://177.21.1.15:9400/Portal_project/;
    }
}
```

Now, this does the proxy from `localhost:8080/jbossSpring/` and `localhost:8080/webpsherePortal/` correctly, however, the pages I get keep requesting files that are located on `localhost:8080/Spring_project/` and `localhost:8080/Portal_project/`.

Is there anyway for me to handle these in nginx? or do I have to modify the Spring/Portal projects to get the right url? (path dependencies probably?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this result by using http rewrite module, documented at  [ngx_http_rewrite_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)

To give an idea, I guess your rewrites shall look like below (I haven't validated this)

```
server {
  ...
  rewrite ^/Spring_project/(.*) /jbossSpring/$1 last;
  rewrite ^/Portal_project/(.*) /webspherePortal/$1 last;
  ...
}
```

Comment: well I am doing rewrites aswell, pretty much like the ones you have there, the problem however seems to be that it's now also sending in the ports from the other servers I'm trying to proxy to, instead of setting the port for the url I'm trying to access :|

Comment: You're right, I certainly missed the ports. Maybe setting "port_in_redirect" directive to "off" and trying to specify the port in target URL may help in this case.